# How to sum time fields javascript HH:MM

Tags: javascript, adobe

I have an adobe pdf that calculates elapsed time, which is working. I however want to sum those times to give a total time in HH:MM format. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SGk9S.png) Anyone have any ideas on the javascript code that could do this?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pznjc.png)

Comment: Can you carify a bit more on what exacltly you wanted to be summed, and what should be the expected result.

Comment: Sure, check the image link above. I have a pdf with rows of elapsed times..in HH:MM. At the end of that column I want to sum all those calculated times, in HH:MM format

Comment: Please add some code which includes your attempt.

Comment: SORRY, but ima. total novice...need help

Answer (score 1):

In case i understand you correctly and you have an array of eplapsedTime as text,
You can run over the values and sum the hours in left part and minutes in right with split.

```js
const flightTimes = ['09:12','12:13','02:55','23:40','05:59'];

let hours = 0, minutes = 0;
flightTimes.forEach((time) => {
  const split = time.split(':');
  hours += parseInt(split[0]);
  minutes += parseInt(split[1]);
});
const formattedNumber = (num) => ("0" + num).slice(-2);
hours += Math.floor(minutes/60);
minutes = minutes % 60;

console.log(formattedNumber(hours) + ':' + formattedNumber(minutes));
```

Comment: Hi Michael. Almost except the Flight Times calculated are not constant, they re driven by calculating the flight time of each row. If nothing in the row, its 0. Hence, not sure how this const works..See above my initial link I posted a picture..

Comment: @MarcGow the constant is for showing the example, you need to create this array. For any other special validation add an undefined check, it's basic...